# Subdirectory doesnt work without slash ("/" symbol)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, slash, trailing

haberimyok.com/tr doesnt work,

haberimyok.com/tr/ works.

.htaccess is in the /web/tr directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?haberimyok.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/tr

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/tr/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?haberimyok.com$

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Thank you.